# RANK vs DENSE_RANK for postgreSQL queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, rank, dense-rank, northwind

I just started learning SQL about a month ago and have been practicing writing queries from the NorthWind sample database on postreSQL in pgAdmin4. After posting about this specific query I am trying to solve the other day, this is what I have come up with:

```
-- Return Month, Product name, SalesForMonth, SalesForMonthRanking for nth best selling product 
-- for each month in 1997
```

This is the query I wrote in order to solve said prompt:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        CAST( EXTRACT( MONTH FROM o.orderdate) AS integer) AS month, 
        p.productname,
        ROUND (CAST (SUM (od.quantity * od.unitprice) AS numeric),2) salesmonth,
        RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY EXTRACT( MONTH FROM o.orderdate)
        ORDER BY SUM (od.quantity * od.unitprice) DESC) monthrank
    FROM order_details od
    INNER JOIN products p ON od.productid = p.productid
    INNER JOIN orders o ON od.orderid = o.orderid
    WHERE o.orderdate >= '1997-01-01' AND o.orderdate <= '1997-12-31'
    GROUP BY EXTRACT( MONTH FROM o.orderdate), p.productname 
) subq
WHERE monthrank = n 
ORDER BY month, monthrank, productname
```

While the result is correct, I noticed that when finding the 27th highest selling product for each month there is no result for month = 6 because there are 2 products tied for the 26th highest selling product. My question is: is this supposed to happen or should I change my RANK statements to DENSE_RANK statements to combat this issue. Also if there is any advice anyone wanted to give me on the actual structure of my query that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you switched it to dense_rank, did it give you the answer you wanted?

Comment: *Also if there is any advice anyone wanted to give me on the actual structure of my query that would be greatly appreciated.* ==> Your query looks good. I would just recommend grouping by product **id** rather than by product **name**. This avoids issues if two different products have the same name.

Comment: @jjanes My questions was more about what would be considered the industry standard for ranking. I thought about it like the Olympics where if there are 2 people that tied for gold, they both get a gold and then a silver and bronze is given out afterwards, they don't give 2 gold medals and then skip the silver and hand out a bronze if that makes sense